Characterization of primitive element.
I would like to characterize primitive elements of field extensions.
I know the classical characterization that an element $\alpha$ is primitive in a finite Galois extension if and only if all its conjugates are distinct.
I wonder if the argument presented here, in which I do not detect the use of normality, is extendable to finite separable extensions. The reason is that the basis of it is that separability makes its roots simple, that conjugates carry roots to roots (of $Irr(\alpha,K)$) and that there are exactly $n$ $K$-homomorphisms of a separable extension $F/K$ to its algebraic closure $\bar{K}/K$. So we play with the coincidence between the degree of the irreducible of $\alpha$ and the degree of the $F/K$ extension (both $n$) as $K \subseteq K(\alpha)\subseteq F$ and $[K(\alpha):K]=n=[F:K]$ ($\Rightarrow F=K(\alpha)$ and $\alpha$ is primitive).
As I say, I don't see where it's wrong or that normality is necessary, but I wanted to ask anyway.
So the question is, is it true the following:
For $F/K$ a separable finite extension of degree $n$ and $\alpha\in F$, the following is true: $\alpha$ is a primitive element if and only if all its conjugates are distinct.
Note:
The definition of conjugates elements is the following:
$\alpha$ and $\beta\in\bar{K}$ are said to be conjugates if and only if it exists $\varphi\in Aut(\bar{K}/K)$ such that $\varphi(\alpha)=\beta$.
We say that "the conjugates of $\alpha$ are all distinct" if the multiset of images of $\alpha$ through those automorphisms has no repeated elements.
(I do not change the terminology "all distinct" cause it is the one used on my bibliography and I don't see it so ambigouos, cause, in other way,"distinct" referring to the collection of images instead of the multiset would be a trivial condition which would always be satisfied).

Hmm.... how are you defining "conjugates"? Usually, if $F$ is an extension of $K$, and $\alpha\in F$, the conjugates of $\alpha$ in $F$ are the roots of the irreducible polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$ that are in $F$, or equivalent, the images under the $K$-automorphisms of $F$. Are you trying to count them with "multiplicity", so that you are looking at the multiset of values of $\alpha$ under $\mathrm{Gal}(F/K)$?

@ArturoMagidin, I edited the post for clarification. Thanks.

There is still a problem. What are the conjugates of $\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$? From what you write, the conjugates are $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$. They are distinct. So then $\sqrt{2}$ is a primitive element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$? No. So what you really mean is that you want it to have as many conjugates as the degree of the extension; equivalently, that it is not fixed by any non-identity automorphism; etc. Not just "its conjugates are distinct".

@ArturoMagidin But there the conjugates are "not distinct", cause I can map $\sqrt{2}$ to $-\sqrt{2}$ either with $i\mapsto$ or $i\mapsto -i$. Wheter you count repetitions or not to speak of "distinct" doesn't matter for the issue. It is just a way to speak.

The very thing of the question is about if normality is also needed in any way or if I can take the argument just with separabiliy.

I am pointing out that the use of "all its conjugates are distinct" is at best confusing/inexact. What are the conjugates of $\sqrt{2}$? They are $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$. Are they distinct (different from each other)? Yes, of course they are. But that is not what you mean. You meant the multiset of images, not merely the collection of images. But your definition just says "it is a conjugate if it is an image". So you need to be much more precise with your language. It is not "just a way to speak", it is an ambiguous way to say something that needs to be precise.

@ArturoMagidin, I added another edit.
